# seaborn library is not updating barplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to draw a barplot. There's one group(nan) that I don't want to see on x-axis, so I filtered it. But, I am still seeing it. I can print and see that nan group has indeed been filtered(please see the dataframe contents below.). Following is the dataframe and graph.

[image]

Following is the filtered dataframe:

```
     channel name      model heuristic     total conversions
0            FB        first touch         104.000000
1           RAD        first touch         112.000000
2            TV        first touch           4.000000
3           OOH        first touch         167.000000
5            FB        last touch          12.000000
6           RAD        last touch         112.000000
7            TV        last touch         259.000000
8           OOH        last touch           4.000000
10           FB        linear touch         120.000000
11          RAD        linear touch          71.333333
12           TV        linear touch         109.666667
13          OOH        linear touch          86.000000
15           FB        markov model          81.561696
16          RAD        markov model          95.122526
17           TV        markov model         120.958421
18          OOH        markov model          89.177205
```

Following is the code that draws the graph:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))

sns.barplot(x="channel name",
            y="total conversions",
            hue="model heuristic",
            data=pychattr_model.melted_data_[0])
plt.xlabel("Channel Name",
           size=20,
           weight="bold")
plt.ylabel("Conversions",
           size=20,
           weight="bold")
plt.title("Total Conversions",
          size=30,
          weight="bold")

plt.show()
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop the `NaN` values from the data you give to the barplot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))

sns.barplot(x="channel name",
            y="total conversions",
            hue="model heuristic",
            data=pychattr_model.melted_data_[0].dropna())
plt.xlabel("Channel Name",
           size=20,
           weight="bold")
plt.ylabel("Conversions",
           size=20,
           weight="bold")
plt.title("Total Conversions",
          size=30,
          weight="bold")

plt.show()
```